# Создание объекта со значениями без undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть код:

```
    let findOptions: any = {};

    if (value) {
        findOptions.value = value;
    }
    if (headers) {
        findOptions.headers = headers;
    }
    if (key) {
        findOptions.key = key;
    }
```

Но мне не нравится, что для создания объекта надо проверять каждое значение на undefined, можно ли как-то его создать, без этих проверок и без использования `delete`?

Exam:

```
const value = '123';
const headers = undefined;
const key = '67';
>>>
{
   value = '123',
   key = '67'
}
```

Comment: Какую цель вы преследуете? Более короткая запись?

Comment: да, более короткую, и есть подозрение что это не очень красивый код и можно сделать как-то лучше

Comment: Где вы проверяете на undefined и зачем используете delete(его у вас в примерах нет)?

Comment: 1. если headers не передали, то там будет undefined, if (headers) -> if (undefined) -> false; 2. "и зачем используете delete(его у вас в примерах нет)" - в вопросе как раз написал, без использования delete

Comment: `if (value)` будет **false** при значениях value - null, 0, '', NaN

Comment: пример с `if` самый простой, и не такой уже длинный. Остальные варианты будут сложнее в понимании и выполнении.

Comment: @SwaD а так же и при undefined https://playcode.io/1522376

Comment: @Ruslan, Swad имел ввиду, что если у тебя false или 0 или другое falsey значение может быть значением поля, то он так же не добавится. Если тебе нужно отсеивать только `undefined` - то в этом случае можешь потерять нужные поля

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите устанавливать свойства объекта с любыми значениями кроме `undefined` и чтобы при этом проверка была встроенной, потому что свойств может быть множество и выполнять проверку каждого из них накладно.

В таком случае вы можете использовать `Proxy` реализовав в нем обработчик `set`:

```
const findOptions: any = new Proxy({}, {
  set(target, prop, value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      target[prop] = value;
    }
    return true;
  },
});

findOptions.value = '123';
findOptions.headers = undefined;
findOptions.key = '67';
findOptions.other = '100';
console.log(findOptions)//{ "value": "123","key": "67","other": "100"}
```

Либо вы можете создать класс с подобной функциональностью, где в сеттере вы также будете проверять значение:

```
class Options {
    private _findOptions: any = {};
    set findOptions({ propertyName, value }) {
        if(value !== undefined){
            this._findOptions[propertyName] = value;
        }  
    }
    get findOptions() {
        return this._findOptions;
    }
}

let options = new Options();
options.findOptions = { propertyName: 'value', value: undefined }; 
console.log(options.findOptions); //  {}
```